# Python OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument when use pd.read_csv with two csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am new here and I need a help.

I got a trouble with ***OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument*** when I tried to use pd.read_csv with two csv files for dataset preprocess.

**I created two dummy dataset as below:**

**test_1.csv:**
DATE,permno,datadate,gvkey, ....... (and a lot of features)
19260130,10006,19260130,3934, ........
19260130,10022,19260130,3942, ........
19260130,10030,19260130,3969, ........
19260130,10049,19260130,3976, ........
19260130,10057,19260130,3977, ........
19260130,10065,19260130,3984, ........
19260130,10073,19260130,3985, ........

**test_2.csv:**
DATE,permno,datadate,Q's ratio
19260130,10006,19260130,1.16541374714217
19260130,10022,19260130,1.01102923080989
19260130,10030,19260130,1.06549175520466
19260130,10049,19260130,1.54355923255147
19260130,10057,19260130,3.56608118773024
19260130,10065,19260130,2.6860629359338
19260130,10073,19260130,2.0303420958083

**my code here:**

```py
import pandas as pd

DATA_DIR = r'C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\test_1.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR, parse_dates=['DATE', 'datadate'])
q = pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR + r'C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\test_2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[1, 3])
```

**I got this error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2021.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/steve/PycharmProjects/Empirical Asset via Machine Learning/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    q = pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR + r'C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\test_2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[1, 3])
  File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Empirical Asset via Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Empirical Asset via Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 586, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Empirical Asset via Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 482, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Empirical Asset via Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 811, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Empirical Asset via Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1040, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
  File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Empirical Asset via Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 51, in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Empirical Asset via Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\base_parser.py", line 222, in _open_handles
    self.handles = get_handle(
  File "C:\Users\steve\PycharmProjects\Empirical Asset via Machine Learning\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 702, in get_handle
    handle = open(
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\steve\\Desktop\\Data\\test_1.csvC:\\Users\\steve\\Desktop\\Data\\test_2.csv'
```

I have searched several similar topics on Stackoverflow, and try but seems no one use pd.read_csv('test_1.csv' + 'test_2.csv', .....) like me

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain `'test_1.csv' + 'test_2.csv',` ?

Comment: test_1.csv is the dummy data from Compustat, this dataset about firm characteristics which would affect the stock market price.

test_2.csv from another source which used to rank the firm, and will shifted/updated by each year.
Then, I tried to call these two csv files in one data.frame, but it happen error. I don't know how it work with the author although I tried to contact him, but he maybe ignore my sms.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing the backslashes'' with forwardslashes'/' fixed it for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\test_1.csvC:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\test_2.csv'

You are trying to read the CSV of an invalid path. You cannot read two csv files at once.

When you call this...

```py
pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR + r'C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\test_2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[1, 3])
```

You are concatenating two absolute paths together, just use...

```py
pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\test_2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[1, 3])
```

A perhaps better way to do this using your `DATA_DIR` would be this...

```py
DATA_DIR = r'C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\'
df = pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR + 'test_1.csv', parse_dates=['DATE', 'datadate'])
pd.read_csv(DATA_DIR + 'test_2.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=[1, 3])
```

Comment: I follow the way you recommend, but I got this error: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: You are missing a closing ' somewhere. I double-checked and the code in my answer has all of the correct '

Comment: I added the closing ' in DATA_DIR = r'C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\'' , but happen another error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\\Users\\steve\\Desktop\\Data\\'test_1.csv"

The original missed closing quote [']

Comment: but if I add \ in DATA_DIR = r'C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\\' . It works but I used print(q). The result just show me three columns of test_2.csv, not both test_1 and test_2

Comment: My apologies, I tested this from a Linux environment and forgot there's weirdness with escape characters in windows paths. Looks like you got it working anyways. LIke I said before, you cannot read in two csv files at once. Take a look at this article for different strategies for merging two dataframes together https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: No, I must say 'thank you', Andrew. Thank for your help and your time. I think I know what you means now, I can not read in two csv files at once. I will follow this direction to fix this code and let it works.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see ure trying to open file path named 'C:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\test_1.csvC:\Users\steve\Desktop\Data\test_2.csv' and its not exist, u have to try create two different variables to open csv,and one to save results.