# Randomly getting "handle = open( OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: Error" in df.to_csv on Windows

Tags: python, pandas

It's working for one run but if I run the code again I 'may' get it. How do I prevent that error from happening? (Eng. Python 3.7X, Windows 12)

Comment: Can you check two things? 1) Are you saving this file to a OneDrive folder? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811910/python-pandas-to-csv-causes-oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument 2) Is the filename valid? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69403282/python-oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument-when-use-pd-read-csv-with-two-csv-fi

Comment: Yes, I am saving in DropBox, (not OneDrive).  Wow, thank you for pointing it out. The solution in first link says upgrade pandas mine is already the latest version. is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: Does pausing sync help?

Comment: No, I already paused sync in the folder where I am writing output data :(

Answer (score 0):

As Nick pointed this may be (most likely) due to DropBox type of folders. This is happening even after the sync is paused. My solution is to catch exceptions and add a delay of 1 second. Not the most efficient but will do the work giving opp. to the sync to finish. And this is happening < 0.1 % of time taking 1 second hit is better than getting runtime exception.

```
def save2csv( cdf, fpath ):
  if cdf.shape[0] == 0: return
  try:
    cdf.to_csv( fpath, sep = ',', encoding = 'utf-8', index = False )
  except:
     time.sleep( 1 )
     cdf.to_csv( fpath, sep = ',', encoding = 'utf-8', index = False )
```